# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: accessibilityHitTest

Tags: java, eclipse, apple-m1

I am getting this error on my M1 Mac. I am running a simple GUI program in Eclipse for a class and getting the error: "Bad JNI lookup accessibilityHitTest" followed by 32 lines of red messages and "Exception in thread "AppKit Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: accessibilityHitTest". I installed Java OpenJDK 17.0.1 through Homebrew, which is the up-to-date version according to homebrew. I do not know how to program in Java and this is my first class learning the language so I am a bit over my head at the moment, but this is the in-class example code that is supposed to be very simple so I am beyond confused as to why this is happening. Thank you to anyone that can provide any help in this situation!

This is what I get from the console window:

```
2023-02-12 07:50:17.847 java[10456:90865] Bad JNI lookup accessibilityHitTest
2023-02-12 07:50:17.849 java[10456:90865] (
    0   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000010dcfc7d1 -[JavaComponentAccessibility accessibilityHitTest:withEnv:] + 153
    1   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000010dcad7e2 -[AWTView accessibilityHitTest:] + 179
    2   AppKit                              0x00007ff81322ff47 -[NSWindow(NSWindowAccessibility) accessibilityHitTest:] + 302
    3   AppKit                              0x00007ff812cfe5ad -[NSApplication(NSApplicationAccessibility) accessibilityHitTest:] + 285
    4   AppKit                              0x00007ff812cbf46b CopyElementAtPosition + 138
    5   HIServices                          0x00007ff8150cb505 _AXXMIGCopyElementAtPosition + 402
    6   HIServices                          0x00007ff8150ed194 _XCopyElementAtPosition + 355
    7   HIServices                          0x00007ff8150aa5a9 mshMIGPerform + 182
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80f8483f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80f848337 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 536
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80f846fb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2749
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80f845e7f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
    12  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff8196d8766 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
    13  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff8196d8576 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 679
    14  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff8196d82b3 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
    15  AppKit                              0x00007ff8128d1293 _DPSNextEvent + 909
    16  AppKit                              0x00007ff8128d0114 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1219
    17  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000010d920653 -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 121
    18  AppKit                              0x00007ff8128c2757 -[NSApplication run] + 586
    19  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000010d920431 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 165
    20  libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000010dd047a1 +[AWTStarter starter:headless:] + 496
    21  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000010d921f73 +[ThreadUtilities invokeBlockCopy:] + 15
    22  Foundation                          0x00007ff8105fd190 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 177
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80f847ed1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80f847e80 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80f847c4e __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80f8468a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 943
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80f845e7f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
    28  libjli.dylib                        0x000000010d3a989d CreateExecutionEnvironment + 381
    29  libjli.dylib                        0x000000010d3a5b45 JLI_Launch + 1253
    30  java                                0x0000000104dd1c15 main + 363
    31  dyld                                0x0000000205073310 start + 2432
)
Exception in thread "AppKit Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: accessibilityHitTest
Hello from the actionPerformed() method!
The button has been pressed.
```

Below is the code I am trying to get to work. It does launch a basic GUI with all three fields but gives me the above-mentioned error whenever I press the button or type into the text box. Also, for some weird reason, the button does not show up as red, but the text box is highlighted in yellow. The java.awt.Color library appears to be working because it is correct for the text box but no matter what I do to get the button to show up in a color it remains a white background. The color chosen is arbitrary and all works for the text box but nothing whatsoever with the button.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyFirstGUI implements ActionListener
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  new MyFirstGUI(); // load self!
  }

JFrame     window    = new JFrame("This is my first GUI program");
JButton    button    = new JButton("Push me!");
JTextField textField = new JTextField("Enter data here and press ENTER.");
JTextArea  textArea  = new JTextArea("Info presented to user here.");

public MyFirstGUI() // CONSTRUCTOR (called by the "new" loader)
  {
  System.out.println("Hi from MyFirstGUI constructor!");
  // Build the GUI
  window.getContentPane().add(button, "North");  // top area 
  window.getContentPane().add(textArea,"Center");// middle area
  window.getContentPane().add(textField,"South");// bottom area
  window.setLocation(500,0); // x,y in "pixels" y=0 is top of window
  window.setSize(500,500); // x,y
  button.setBackground(Color.red);
  textField.setBackground(Color.yellow);
  textArea.setEditable(false); // keep cursor out
  window.setVisible(true); // show it!
  window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  button.addActionListener(this);   // call me when pushed!
  textField.addActionListener(this);// call me when ENTER key! 
  } 

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
  if (ae.getSource() == button)
     {
     System.out.println("Button was pushed!");
     }
  if (ae.getSource() == textField)
     {
     System.out.println("TextField had data entry!");
     String input = textField.getText();
     textField.setText(""); // clear!
     textArea.setText(input); 
     }

  }
}
```

I have updated every possible piece of software and compared this to what I get on my Intel-based Mac. The issue is mostly solved using all the same software on that computer so this leads me to believe there is an issue running OpenJDK Java 17.0.1 on M1 Macs.

Possible complications to consider:

- Is it that I am using an M1 Mac? This is what I think is the main concern…
  If I run this on my old 2016 intel Mac running macOS Monterey 12.6.3 (the newest it can run) I can get it to run the GUI without error (but the red button still shows up white).
  How can I get this to run properly on my M1 Mac?!? It is nice that I can get it running on my old laptop but it doesn't help solve the issue.
- My professor is ancient and is probably using an older version of Java, if this is the case is there’d reason an older version of java would cause this problem?
  This is just a question, I have no way of testing this.
- Is this something to do with my software versions?
  I updated to MacOS 13.2 Ventura and have updated home-brew, java, and eclipse. I do not think this is the issue but I am using pretty basic java software and simple code so I am not sure how many issues there could be.
- Is it something to do with Eclipse?
  I tested this by running the application in terminal and it acted exactly the same. The correct information displays on the GUI but no red button and the same error is happening.

Comment: I used homebrew to install "zulu" which is the cask for Java 19.0.2 AzulJDK, which allowed the program to run in terminal just fine (minus the red button issue that persists) but eclipse still does not run properly at all. Do I need to do something to make eclipse use AzulJDK instead of OpenJDK?

Comment: I figured out how to update eclipse to run the new version of Java and this link was incredibly helpful for anyone else experiencing this issue: [link](https://marco.dev/change-the-jre-jdk-in-eclipse-on-mac-os-x-and-access-the-sources)

Comment: When using native libraries via JNI, the libraries and the Java VM must be of the same architecture, including 32 bit or 64 bit. In the properties _Java > Installed JREs_ you have configure the JDKs to be used in your project (_Project > Properties_). It should work with JDK/Java VM of any vendor, but, as said before, the native libraries must match the architecture of the Java VM (and on a M1 mac you can run at least  x86_64 and AArch64 Java VMs).